# Is "According to Evangelicals" too broad?

Tags: discussion

In the same vein as [Is it valid to ask if “Christianity” teaches anything?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/)

"Evangelicals" is a [pretty broad term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelicalism) that includes a pretty wide range of beliefs.  is it valid to scope questions "according to Evangelicals"?

Example question: [According to Evangelicals, who now has the authority to bind and loose (per Matt. 18:18)?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/45995/)

Note that I'm not saying it's too broad or not.  I'm asking for community input.

Comment: I tend to think that the biggest problem with such questions is that people have a lot of different ideas about what "evangelical" means. If we can nail that down, then we're on better footing. But even then, I think some such questions would be "too broad" and others would not, depending on other factors. Thanks for asking this, by the way.

Comment: Just like [the question on protestantism](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1913/6071) the answer is "sometimes". If you don't know the answer to the question then you won't know whether there's a single position or not. But others will, and can vote to close it if it would be too broad, or suggest it be edited into an overview question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. No. Maybe so.

Much like I mentioned in [the discussion about the Protestant tag](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1915/30), I think the answer to this is highly dependent on the content of the question. Only experts with some experience in in the specific topic raised will be able to determine whether the question scope is reasonable. To the uninitiated any given question may seem like it has an easy answer and actually require a thesis paper to address properly, or it could seem like a broad issues but really there are only a couple of positions and a modest sized answer could break out the themes.

I don't think any formula can determine whether a question is or is not going to be too broad. Some (rare) questions may even address "all of Christianity" and be answerable on this site, while some questions about the beliefs of very small denominations might be so involved it's best to split them up or narrow the focus to a single side of a theological divide.